# When are Azure Cloud Service virtual machine recreated

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

I have a cloud service project with deployment settings

- "Delete deplyment on failure" - unchecked
- "Deployment update" - checked

  - "If deployment can't be updated, do a full deployment" - unchecked

When I deploy a new version it seems the virtual machine is always intact and it just creates a new disk with my code which it attaches as either E: or F:.

Will a deployment ever create a new vm or will it always use the existing vm. Will new VMs only be created when the VM template is updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From our experience, Cloud Services Updates will always use the current deployed instances, they won't create new ones, **unless** you are modifying the amount or size of instances: [Taken from here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-how-to-manage/#how-to-update-a-cloud-service-role-or-deployment)

You might want to consider having a Staging / Production pair of environments and doing a Swap.

When we used Cloud Services, our Staging environment was always empty, we deployed there, then swapped and then deleted the Staging (former Production) deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have a deployment that installs some additional stuff on the machine. Now the installation is broken and I don't want to do a full install because that would generate a new ip for the cloud service which means that some firewalls would need to be reconfigured.

Comment: You can reserve IPs for Cloud Services to have static IPs assigned. Once you [obtain the Reserved IP] (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/reserved-ip-addresses/), you can assign it on the Cloud Service configuration file. It does have an extra cost though.